# Ruby On Rails On Azure Ubuntu Virtual Machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, azure

I have created one Ubuntu Virtual Machine on windows Azure for deploying my rails application. I am using the following steps for accessing my app..

1. Doing SSH to my app `xxx.cloudapp.net`
2. Giving `rails s` command in my app directory.

I am able to view my app running on azure cloud. But the problem is server gets stopped for every 10-15 minutes and again I need to restart my server with `rails s`

Am I following the correct procedure or is there any other method to keep the server continuously running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend running the built-in rails server in this environment, as it is only meant for your local development environment.

Since you're on Windows Azure I would recommend you take a look at this tutorial from the Azure folks. It shows how to setup a nginx web server along with unicorn to host a Rails application.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/ruby/tutorials/web-app-with-capistrano/